# How to route specific urls in a django app?

Tags: python, django

I would like to know if there is a way to include only specific url endpoints in my Django urls.py.

Lets say i have a app called auth with this auth/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^password/reset/$', PasswordResetView.as_view(),
        name='rest_password_reset'),
    url(r'^password/reset/confirm/$', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
        name='rest_password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='rest_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='rest_logout'),
    url(r'^user/$', UserDetailsView.as_view(), name='rest_user_details'),
    url(r'^password/change/$', PasswordChangeView.as_view(),
        name='rest_password_change'),
]
```

Now I have a urls.py like that:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls'))
]
```

this includes all endpoints from auth/urls.py.

Is there a way to select (in urls.py) which URL to include? Lets say I only want login and logout to be included on my urls.py.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls.rest_login')),
    path('/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls.rest_logout'))
]
```

Something like that, how can I make it work?

Comment: Why would you want that? Could it be to 'hide' some URLs? In that case, take a look at auth decorators, for example.
I believe it is not possible to use Django's `include` to include only part of the URLs, I take that from its description [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#include).

Comment: Exactly, to hide some urls. Since the app is imported, I woudn't like to modify it. I just wanted to hide unwanted urls. I will take a look at auth decorators, thank you.

Comment: Nice. How much is that "I wouldn't like to modify it"? The decorator can redirect to another page based on conditions (usually login status), and to implement it it's as simple as adding one line before the respective route function/method implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this long before.

```py
# inside view.py just create your own custom view

# rest and rest_auth import
from rest_auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView


class CustomLogoutView(LogoutView):
    # yes u can keep it blank.
    # over-riding just to distinguish from library views.
    pass
```

Then inside any app's urls.py import required views and and pass then into path.
this way only required url will be exposed.

```py
from .views import CustomLoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

Also you can directly import that views (not urls) which are included in library. and then create urls (path) from them.